# Why is explicit specialization in non-namespace scope forbidden?

Tags: c++, templates

I know that explicit specialization in non-namespace scope is forbidden by the standard. For example, this:

```
template <class A>
class Outer {
    template <class B>
    class Inner {};

    template <>
    class Inner<A> {};
};
```

Will give the `Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope` error. I understand what is the error and how to avoid it with an extra dummy parameter (it could also be avoided by putting the `Inner` class outside and adding an extra parameter to it, which I would like to avoid as certain older compilers have trouble with *partial* template specialization).

However, it seems that doing that gives actually more work to the compiler. My question is - **why is** explicit specialization in non-namespace scope **forbidden**? What was the motivation to impose this?

I understand that there are plenty more questions on the subject ([C++: Nested template classes error "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301966/c-nested-template-classes-error-explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-sco), [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope), [C++: error "explicit specialization in non-namespace scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746419/c-error-explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope)), however I believe that mine is **not a duplicate**, as I do not ask how to fix the issue, like those questions do.

Comment: Right, looks like I failed to find that. Seems to me that there are no strong fact-supported answers, though, more like guesses.

Comment: More [unanswered questions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.std.c$2B$2B/explicit$20specialization$20in$20non-namespace$20scope/comp.std.c++/es4iP4ZFqLY/FuVyCbo08qAJ).